# New to Android Studio: How to add custom text into ListView/ListAdapter results?

Tags: android, listview

I have a silly question here. I am also new to these, please show some codes if possible.

**Android Studio: How to append a custom text into ListView/ListAdapter?**

- I would like to add the extra text before my raw Stock ID.

  > Example: Product ID: 1, 
  >   Product ID: 2
- raw Stock ID is obtained from a Database server using php sql.

[image: Screenshot of the app]

I tried use this following line to do this but there is some problem because I'm going to reference ***Config.TAG_ID*** in my **onItemClick function** to pass it to the next activity.

> //employees.put(Config.TAG_ID, "ID: " + id);

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewStock.class);
    HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String empId = map.get(Config.TAG_ID).toString();
    intent.putExtra(Config.STOCK_ID, empId);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Function that shows my stock list

```
private void showEmployee() {
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = jo.getString(Config.TAG_ID);
            String name = jo.getString(Config.TAG_NAME);
            String price = jo.getString(Config.TAG_PRICE);

            HashMap<String, String> employees = new HashMap<>();
            employees.put(Config.TAG_ID, id);
            //employees.put(Config.TAG_ID2, "ID: " + id);
            employees.put(Config.TAG_NAME, "Product name: " + name);
            employees.put(Config.TAG_PRICE, "Price: ($)" + price);
            list.add(employees);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            ViewAllStock.this, list, R.layout.list_item,
            new String[]{ Config.TAG_ID, Config.TAG_NAME, Config.TAG_PRICE},
            new int[]{ R.id.id, R.id.name, R.id.price});

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

***EDITED: Error picture for GreyWolf's answers:***
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SimpleAdapter's setViewBinder() method to provide a binder that will translate the data into text fields to set in your view.

Setup your data as follows:

```
        HashMap<String, String> employees = new HashMap<>();
        employees.put(Config.TAG_ID, id);
        employees.put(Config.TAG_NAME, name);
        employees.put(Config.TAG_PRICE, price);
        list.add(employees);
```

And your adapter as follows:

```
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            ViewAllStock.this, list, R.layout.list_item,
            new String[]{ Config.TAG_ID, Config.TAG_NAME, Config.TAG_PRICE},
            new int[]{ R.id.id, R.id.name, R.id.price});
    adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String textRepresentation) {
            if (view.getId() == R.id.id) {
                 TextView v = (TextView) view;
                 v.setText("Product ID: " + textRepresentation);
                 return true;
            } else if (view.getId() == R.id.name) {
                 TextView v = (TextView) view;
                 v.setText("Product Name: " + textRepresentation);
                 return true;
            } else if (view.getId() == R.id.price) {
                 TextView v = (TextView) view;
                 v.setText("Price: ($)" + textRepresentation);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now the data values remain pure and can be passed unaltered in your activity intent.

Comment: Hi, Im having an error. Unable to resolve method 'setViewBinder......' (Updated: Error picture posted in question)

Comment: Whoops sorry.  Change the type of adapter variable to SimpleAdapter so that the compiler finds the setViewBinder() method, which is not available in the base ListAdapter class.  I've edited the example to correct this.

Comment: If this fixed your problem could you please mark as correct?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi, replacing the type of adapter gives FATAL EXCEPTION error at line 81.

Comment: Line 81 ERROR----->> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map

Comment: Line 81----->> Map<String, String> dataMap = (Map)data;

Comment: Edited again.  Looks like the values are passed from the map, not the map itself.

Comment: The edited codes works! Mind explaining what you did there? Another way I tried is to create another Key for 'id'=TAG_ID_RAW in HashMap, a Key which is different from the first Key used for 'id'=TAG_ID. Then in onItemClick, I used map.get(Config.TAG_ID_RAW).toString();

Comment: Each time the adapter calls the ViewBinder it looks up a view by the id given in the to array that you passed in as the last parameter of the constructor.  That specific view is passed in to the setViewValue() method.  Also, it looks up the corresponding  value from the map and passes it as the data parameter, and a string representation in the textRepresentation parameter.  Each time the method is called we check which view is getting passed in, and then set the appropriate prefix text based upon the view id, concatenated with the string representation provided by the data.

Answer (score 1):

employees.put(Config.TAG_ID, "Product ID"+id);

Comment: You have to make a Pogo class which contain id,productName and Price. implements getter and setter

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ProductPogo {
String id;
String productName;
String price;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public String setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
    return id;
}

public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}

public String setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
    return productName;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public String setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
    return price;
}
```

}

```
//in your doInBackground
JSONObject productJsonObject = myPriceJsonArray.getJSONObject(p);

id =productPogo.setId("Product ID"+productJsonObject.getString("id"));
productName = productPogo.setProductName(productJsonObject.getString("productName"));
 = productPogo.setPrice(productJsonObject.getString("price"));

yourArraylist.add(productPogo);

//InOnItemClickListner
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("product_id", yourArraylist.get(position).getId());
```